# clang enum overflow

Tags: c, enums, overflow

Using -Wall -pedantic

```
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    enum x {
        a,
        max = INT_MAX,
        out_1
    };
    enum y {
        b,
        out_2 = INT_MAX + 1
    };


    printf("%d %d\n", out_1, out_2);
    return 0;
}
```

clang returns

```
demo.c:9:3: warning: overflow in enumeration value
                out_1
                ^
```

As you can see, compiler does not warn about out_2 overflow, his value is unknown at compile time?

Comment: Pretty sure the standard does not define the range of an `enum`.

Comment: My guess: it evaluates INT_MAX+1 first, which would wrap around and assigns that to out_2.

Comment: @johnny: no, it invokes UB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first instance, the compiler itself is trying to pick an integer that is causing an overflow, and so is warning you. It is likely producing `INT_MIN`. The standard allows for any value in a `signed int` to be an enum constant (see bottom).

In the second, the expression `(INT_MAX + 1)` is calculated before it is assigned to `out_2`. An overflow in the expression here is producing a result that is allowed, but this is undefined behaviour. The valid result is then stored in the enum, which is why the first error isn't produced.

clang (3.2) will also not warn about this, which is effectively identical:

```
int a = INT_MAX + 1;
```

In this respect, clang is not behaving according to the C standard, as this is undefined.

The output from gcc in comparison makes the difference completely clear:

```
In function ‘main’:
9:9: error: overflow in enumeration values
13:25: warning: integer overflow in expression [-Woverflow]
```

The Intel compiler ignores the enum overflow, but warns about the integer overflow:

```
enum.c(13): warning #61: integer operation result is out of range
      out_2 = INT_MAX + 1
                      ^
```

---

For reference, from the C99 standard 6.7.7.2.2, "The expression that deﬁnes the value of an enumeration constant shall be an integer constant expression that has a value representable as an `int`; .3, "The identiﬁers in an enumerator list are declared as constants that have type `int` and may appear wherever such are permitted." i.e. an enum constant may be any `int` value, and has an `int` type. The resulting type of a defined enum variable can be `char`, `int` or `unsigned int`, as long as it allows for all the possible constants in the enum. As such both `enums` in the example are undefined, as they both require an integer overflow. The first is explicitly illegal.

Comment: But the question was: why does Clang **not** warn about out_2.

Comment: @eznme: the second point - the integer is a valid enum after the expression is calculated, in this instance.

Comment: @eznme I'd guess it's because `-Wall` is a misnomer. With `-Weverything`, or probably even `-Wextra`, I'd expect clang to warn about the overflow.

Comment: @DanielFischer: no warning with either of those with clang 3.2. gcc warns without any -W options.

Comment: @eznme Signed int overflow is totally undefined.

Comment: @eznme: this is about signed ints though, so INT_MAX + 1 is undefined.

Comment: @teppic Indeed. Colour me surprised.

Answer (score 0):

ISO C specifies integers as enum-values.

If your compiler allows it (and GCC and Clang do) then INT_MIN is a perfectly fine value.

If the compiler would not allow a *specified* index then it is required issue an **error**.

The reason why an explicitly requested INT_MIN is fine but an auto-increased value from the INT_MAX predecessor issues a **warning** is, that the standard requires **+1** Behavior.

Comment: but `enum` constants are `int`.

Comment: @ouah yes as i said. (the 4th word i used)

Comment: so you admit an `enum` constant of `INT_MIN` has to be accepted by all C compilers?

Comment: @ouah NO. read what i wrote! i wrote "but the range is implementation-dependent"!

Comment: but you should. As `enum` constants are `int`, C compilers are required to accept `INT_MIN`.

Comment: @ouah wrong. ISO C says it exactly like i did. Values 0...1023 are required.

Comment: *C99, 6.7.2.2p2 : The expression that defines the value of an enumeration constant shall be an integer constant expression that has a value representable as an int* and *6.7.2.2p3: The identifiers in an enumerator list are declared as constants that have type int and may appear wherever such are permitted*

Comment: @ouah: every square is a rectangle, but not every rectangle is a square. Every enum constant is representable as an integer, but not every integer must be acceptable as an enum constant.

Comment: "*298 —  1023 enumeration constants in a single enumeration*" http://c0x.coding-guidelines.com/5.2.4.1.html

Comment: @eznme: The statement "with a minimum of 0...1023 required" is incorrect.  Any `int` can be an enumeration value.  Read the link you just cited a little more carefully, it doesn't say what you claim it says.

Comment: @eznme: that means different 1023 different constants within an enumeration, not the values 0-1023. The standard is clear that an enumeration is an int, and can be fully compatible with a signed int.

Comment: Removed the stuff about the 1023. It is irrelevant to the answer anyway. The point is that INT_MIN is fine but INT_MAX followed by another +1'ed entry is not.