# Range of and convertibility between different enum types

Tags: c, enums, language-lawyer

**Under which conditions can one convert from one enumerated type to another?**

Let's consider the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  enum enum_tag_1 { language } c = language;
  enum enum_tag_2 { lawyer = 256 } d = lawyer;
  d = c;
  c = 2;
  printf("%d\n", c);
  printf("%d\n", d);
}
```

We can now ask questions such as whether statements like `c = 2;` and `d = c;` are guaranteed to work.

The C17 standard says (draft, 6.7.2.2):

> ¶3 The identifiers in an enumerator list are declared as constants that have type `int`. [...]
> ¶4 Each enumerated type shall be compatible with `char`, a signed integer type, or an unsigned integer type. The choice of type is implementation-defined,[] but shall be capable of representing the values of all the members of the enumeration. [...]

That is, it seems that **an enumerated type** is simply ***a possibly implementation-defined integer type chosen by the implementation to be large enough for the given enumerator list, whose enumerators must all be of type `int`***.

That is:

- `enum enum_tag_1` is a possibly implementation-defined type large enough to contain the `int` `0`. This could be `_Bool` or a custom type whose range is {-1, 0, 1}. That is, the assignment `c = 2;` is not necessarily legal.
- `enum enum_tag_2` is a possibly implementation-defined type large enough to contain the `int` `256`. This implies that it can at least hold the range [0, 1, ..., 511] (but not necessarily 512). Therefore the assignment `d = language` (value `0`) is always legal. `d = c;` is legal in the above code, but assigning from `enum enum_tag_1` to `enum enum_tag_2` is not necessarily allowed for all values, since the former might be `signed` and the latter might be `unsigned`.
- Even though the enumeration constants for `enum enum_tag_1` and `enum enum_tag_2` can only have values fitting into the type `int`, it is legal for the implementation to makes these types so big that one can assign very large numbers to them, like this:
  `c = −9223372036854775808;`
  `d = 18446744073709551615;`

This relies on the fact that integer types always have ranges of the form [0, 2<sup>*N*</sup>-1] (unsigned) or [-2<sup>*N*</sup>(+1), 2<sup>*N*</sup>-1] (signed), where *N* is the number of value bits (C17 standard, draft, 6.2.6.2 ¶1-2). (See this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30408698/2057969).)

But what about the general case? It seems that inter-convertibility of `enum`s **depends on the ranges** of the types which the implementation chooses, making the answer **implementation-dependent**.

Comment: An interesting side question is whether an implementation can choose barely fitting integer types in one compilation run and overly large integer types during the next compilation run, despite the code not having changed.

Comment: In short, your assignments will work. They might now have any meaning or make sense in your program, but they will work.

Comment: "now" --> "not"

Comment: These points from K&R (pg. 196) could be useful: Enumerations are unique types that have integral values; ... it is common for a compiler to issue a warning when an object of a particular enumeration type is assigned something other than one of its constants, or an expression of its type.

Comment: @Hari Thanks. I looked up the corresponding section from the C17 standard draft, and it is: Annex I [Common warnings] ¶2. The bullet points there list situations when warnings are commonly issued; the relevant one here is: "A value is given to an object of an enumerated type other than by assignment of an enumeration constant that is a member of that type, or an enumeration object that has the same type, or the value of a function that returns the same enumerated type (6.7.2.2)."

Comment: Perhaps relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/q/70988698/1778275.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given what I researched for this question in the C17 standard and elsewhere (see original question), I believe that the correct answer is the following:

- It is always legal for an implementation to make any enumerated type identical to `int`.

  - Even though this would make the enumerated types interchangeable with each other, the various enumerator lists must be pairwise disjoint; that is, they can't share enumeration constants.
- The range of the enumerated type must be of the form above, that is [0, 2<sup>*N*</sup>-1] (unsigned) or [-2<sup>*N*</sup>(+1), 2<sup>*N*</sup>-1] (signed), with any of these choices being legal, as long as the enumeration constants from the enumerator list are covered.

  - These ranges define what values can be assigned to variables of these `enum` types, irrespective of whether there are `int` enumeration constants with those values in the respective enumerator lists.
- One can convert an *individual* value of type `enum A` to type `enum B` if it happens to fall into the range of the underlying integer type of `enum B`.
- One can convert *all* values of type `enum A` to type `enum B` if the implementation has chosen respective integer types `type_a` and `type_b` for them where the range of the former is a subset of the range of the latter.

  - One can work out conditions under which conversions of enumeration constants of type `enum A` to `enum B` are *guaranteed* to work. The details would be cumbersome to write up, but for instance, if all enumeration constants of `enum A` fall into the range [-511, 511], all these constants (but not necessarily all values of type `enum A`) are convertible to `enum B` if that type has constants `-1` and `511` in its enumerator list.

Answer (score 3):

NordicSemi has an opinion piece on this topic here: https://developer.nordicsemi.com/nRF_Connect_SDK/doc/1.9.2-dev1/tfm/docs/technical_references/design_docs/enum_implicit_casting.html

... from which I quote:

> According to the C99 standard 1:
>
> §6.2.5, 16: An enumeration comprises a set of named integer constant
> values. Each distinct enumeration constitutes a different numerated
> type.
>
> §6.7.2.2, 2: The expression that defines the value of an enumeration
> constant shall be an integer constant expression that has a value
> representable as an int.
>
> §6.7.2.2, 3: The identifiers in an enumerator list are declared as
> constants that have type int and may appear wherever such are
> permitted.
>
> §6.7.2.2, 4: Each enumerated type shall be compatible with char, a
> signed integer type, or an unsigned integer type. The choice of type
> is implementation-defined, but shall be capable of representing the
> values of all the members of the enumeration.
>
> From these four quotes from the C99 standard 1, the following
> conclusions can be made:
>
> - an enumeration defines a new type and should be treated as such
> - the enumeration constants must only contains value representable as an `int`
> - the enumeration constants have type `int`
> - the actual type of the enumeration can be between `char`, signed and unsigned `int`. The compiler chooses the type it wants among those
>   that can represent all declared constants of the enumeration.

The conclusion:

> it is always safe to assign an enumeration constant to an int, but
> might be better to cast to show intent.
>
> when casting an enumeration constant to another type, it should be
> checked that the constant can fit into the destination type.
>
> when casting from an integer type (`uint32_t`, `int32_t`, etc) to an
> enumeration type, it should be checked that the integer’s value is one
> of the enumeration constants. The comparison needs to be done on the
> biggest type of the two so that no information is lost. C integer
> promotion should automatically do that for the programmer (check
> §6.3.1.8, 1 for the rules).
>
> when casting from an enumeration type to an integer type, it should be
> checked that the enumeration type value fits into the integer type.
> The value of a variable which has the type of an enumeration type is
> not limited to the enumeration constants of the type. An enumeration
> constant will always fit into an `int`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to this. I disagree with the essence of it: (1) The C99 standard's wording (which the linked post is based on) does, like C17, not specifically require `char`, `signed int`, or `unsigned int` (the post's code formatting is slightly different, but from reading the whole thing it's clear that this is what is meant). (2) Custom types [should be okay](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30418074/2057969). // I am still unclear about the significance of the "new type" and "compatible with" wordings.

Comment: I think the intent is to let the implementation choose a smaller type if the enumeration constants fit in. `int` being faster on a given architecture can factor into the decision.

Comment: @LoverofStructure I think we are in agreement. I know that many versions of clang and gcc will allow using 8-bit enums of you optimize for size `-Os` for instance.

Comment: Yeah it's not very clear IMO. From the C99 standard [linked in the post](https://open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/WG14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) §6.7.2.2, page 105 `Constraints: The expression that defines the value of an enumeration constant shall be an integer constant expression that has a value representable as an int.. I.e. should be representable as int.` - but `sizeof(int)` depends on the target architecture. Whether or not it should also fit a char, short, uint32 etc. is therefore also implementation-defined as I understand it. That's also how I read Keith Thompson's post in your link.